# URL Issue where the URL keeps extending

Tags: magento-1.9, url

I have just launched my 2nd Magento store on calzeat.com and i am having an issue where going between certain pages the url doesn't work right. For example when i go to calzeat.com/contact then i click on the Stores link it will try to go to calzeat.com/contact/stores. Really Strange.

Only between a few pages in certain directions it happens.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't check your site, but your links are most likely relative.

E.g.

```
<a href="stores">Stores</a>
```

That link will go to `example.com/stores` if you're on `example.com`, but if you're on `example.com/contact/`, it'll go to `example.com/contact/stores`.

The solution is to use absolute URLs (`Mage::getUrl('stores')`), or at least a leading slash (`/stores` instead of 'stores'). The leading slash is not recommend as it does not allow installations into subdirectories, etc.